# A question about gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, black-holes, speed-of-light, gravitational-waves

Some time ago I encouraged by 11 year old son to watch Cosmos: A Spacetime Odyssey with Neil DeGrasse Tyson, and subsequently Cosmos: A personal Voyage with Carl Sagan, as well as other astronomy shows including History Channel's The Universe.
One of these such shows inspired a question about black holes and gravity.

Can a black hole be so large that not even the effects of its own gravity can escape?

Perhaps the question rephrased might be: Why are gravitational waves immune to the effects of gravity?

Comment: "Why are gravity waves immune to the effects of gravity?" I think this is a nice question, and Id suggest you to edit your post to use this as your title, and not just "A question about gravity", which might be a bit vague.

Comment: Gravity *waves* are not a good rephrasing because gravity is not communicated by *waves* (and neither is the electromagnetic force communicated by light), especially not classically. Regardless, this question is a duplicate of [How does gravity escape a black hole?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/937/50583)

Comment: @ACuriousMind The retarded electric field is propagated as a wave, so there is a sense in which the electric force is communicated by a wave.  I would presume that gravity has a similar construction, but I don't know enough to say for certain.

Comment: @BenitoCiaro: A photon is not an electromagnetic wave (although a classical electromagnetic wave is made up out of many photons), and you should not take virtual particles to be actual particles.

Answer (score 2):

Gravitational* waves (GW) are *not* immune to the effects of general relativity (i.e. gravity).  If there was a source of GWs inside the event horizon, they would *not* emanate out of it (e.g. [this answer --- which, *I think*, is much better than the accepted answer on that question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/975/8521)).

At the same time, **the 'information' about the gravitational field which is experienced/observed outside of an event-horizon has *always been* outside the event horizon --- and thus does not need to be 'communicated' out**.

Consider, for example, if our sun collapsed entirely into a black-hole (e.g. [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7732/if-the-sun-were-to-suddenly-become-a-black-hole-of-the-same-mass-what-would-the)).  The gravity outside of it wouldn't actually change (assuming the mass of the sun was completely preserved into the black-hole) at all.  The 'information' about the black-hole's mass is already (and has always been) outside of the event horizon.  If additional matter falls into the black-hole (e.g. [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25556/can-we-see-a-spaceship-falling-into-a-black-hole-and-entering-the-event-horizon)), the 'information' about it still stays on the outside --- in particular, one can think of it as being imprinted onto the event-horizon.

Regarding your initial question of,

> Can a black hole be so large that not even the effects of its own gravity can escape?

The answer is thus, *no*; but I'd also like to point out that black-holes are *'scale-invariant'* --- in that none of the physics changes as the total size/mass increases.

Side-Note:
*['Gravity Waves'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_wave) are (unfortunately) a term often used for certain types of *sound*-waves *caused by gravity* in stars, so the term 'gravitational waves' is preferable.  This usage is not universal.

Comment: @BenitoCiaro not outside of the mass distribution, no.

Comment: @BenitoCiaro, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law_for_gravity, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem,  http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/54066/8521, http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/140889/8521, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81324/why-gravity-decreases-as-we-go-under-ground/81327#81327